# python GPIO.output no funciona

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Tengo una raspberry pi 4 con el sistema operativo raspbian.
estoy haciendo un script en python para encender automaticamente el ventilador cuando la temperatura sea mayor que 50. Todo funciona bien, pero cuando lo "enciende" imprime en la consola "ON" pero realmente no enciende el ventilador. la parte del codigo que controla el GPIO es esta

```
fan = 12
min_temp = 40
max_temp = 50

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(fan, GPIO.OUT)

while(True):
    cpu_temp = get_temp()
    print(cpu_temp)

    try:
        if(cpu_temp >= max_temp):
            if(not GPIO.input(fan)):
                GPIO.output(fan, True)
                print(" ON")
        else:
            if(cpu_temp <= min_temp and GPIO.input(fan)):
                GPIO.output(fan, False)
                print("OFF")
    except:
        print("Some errors")
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(fan, GPIO.OUT)
    time.sleep(3)
```

En la raspberry tengo el ventilador conectados a los pines 12 y 14, donde el 14 es GND (si paso el pin del 12 al de 5v (pin 2) el ventilador enciende)) no se por que no está encendiendo.

Comment: ¿Lo tienes conectado al pin físico 12, correcto?

Comment: @jachguate Si, lo tengo conectado al pin 12 correcto, teniendo los puertos a la derecha y contando de izquierda a derecha solo en la fila de arriba, están el positivo y negativo conectados a los pines 6 y 7 respectivamente, repito, contando de izquierda a derecha solo los pines de la fila de arriba. pero si, están donde deberían

Comment: No es por nada, pero si conectas el ventilador a una fuente de 3 voltios, aún se mueve, correcto?

Comment: @jachguate si tambien se mueve, lo probé antes de hacer el programa, los GPIO solo sacan 3v

Comment: @jachguate tomé un vultimetro y efectivamente funciona el codigo, salen los 3v cuando está ON y cuando está OFF en el codigo salen 0v, ya no entiendo entonces que sucede, porque si conecto el ventilador a 3v osea al pin 1 si enciende, sabes por que pasa?

Comment: El pin 1 da 5v, ¿no?. Puede ser que el ventilador funcione con 5v, pero no alcance a funcionar con 3v

Comment: @jachguate no, el 2 y 4 dan 4v, el 1 da 3v

Comment: Debo confesar que la electrónica no es lo mío, pero en los ejemplos que veo, usan un transistor: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hamzab70/Raspberry-Pi-Fan-Script/master/Electrical-Scheme.png ¿seguro que no lo necesitas?

Comment: @jachguate gracias, voy a probarlo y te comento